# Swap Cache Memory during continues application lookup

Tags: caching, ignite

Step 1: Application1 computes and store some data in Ignite memory
Step 2: Application2, 3 .... N (Multiple applications) consumes and process business functionality, this continues and millions of transactions takes place without break

After Some time:
Step 3: Applicaiton1 computes upgraded data and stores in Ignite Memory

Question:
I want to swap/upgrade Step1 Cache memory with Step3 data without interrupting Step2 process

How can I achieve this?
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What cache mode are you on?

Comment: Its Partitioned Mode

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot seemlessly swap caches on the fly. You should either update the target cache without making a temp one, or implement some switch-over for the Step 2. Also, if Step 3 is short, you can perform it in a single transaction.